# Reduce the computation and storage burden for row-wise comparison in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, computation

Consider we have the following data frame:

```
      message
0       ABC
1       abc
2       cba
3      abcd
4      dcsa
5      adcd
6      abcd
7       cba
```

I want to perform row-wise comparisons, then finally group the data using the similarity vector for some metric calculation.

For now, I am doing the following:

```
     message      similarity
0       ABC  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
1       abc  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
2       cba  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
3      abcd  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
4      dcsa  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
5      adcd  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
6      abcd  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
7       cba  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

From the above, it is clear that I am doing a brute-force job. That being said, starting from row 1, I compare it with all the rows (including itself), and if they have sufficient similarity, then I store it as `1`, otherwise it is `0`, and thus, the vector size is the number of rows (`N`), and it is a `O(N^2)` problem. For a smaller dataset, this is acceptable, but it does not scale for bigger datasets. For example, let us imagine that there are `1M` rows, and for each row, there is a `1M`-sized similarity vector—this is really crazy.

Therefore, I am here for input regarding two questions:

1. Can we reduce the `O(N^2)` complexity? My current thought is we can order the `message` column and perform comparison on a reduced basis. e.g., for row1, comparing it with row2 till rowN, and for row2, comparing it with row3 till rowN, etc. But the similarity vector will vary on its length among all the rows.
2. Is there a better way to store the similarity vector? We need it for grouping purpose, and thus, such a vector is unavoidable. Can we use another method to handle it?

A minimal reproducible example is provided below to play with.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['ABC', 'ABCD', 'DCBA', 'abcde', 'CBDA', 'abcde', 'edcba']})

def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    coef = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2).ratio()
    if coef >= 0.75:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def similarity(x, df):
    sim_score = []
    for i in df['message']:
        sim_score.append(similarity_score(x, i))
    return sim_score

df['similarity'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: similarity(x, df)).astype(str)
```

Below I'd like to illustrate my motivation for the questions above using a reproducible example. For each message, there is an count (`cnt`). After the similarity vector (`similarity`) is created, I used it as a grouping variable to categorize the message into different groups (`group`), and finally, sum up the count per group.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['ABC','abc','cba','abcd','dcsa','adcd','abcd','cba'], 
                  'cnt': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    coef = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2).ratio()
    if coef >= 0.80:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def similarity(x,df):
    sim_score = []
    for i in df['message']:
        sim_score.append(similarity_score(x, i))
    return sim_score

df['similarity'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: similarity(x, df)).astype(str)
df["group"] = pd.factorize(df["similarity"].astype(str))[0] + 1
print(df)
```

The output is as follows:

```
   message  cnt         similarity          group
0     ABC    1  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      1
1     abc    2  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]      2
2     cba    3  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]      3
3    abcd    4  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]      2
4    dcsa    5  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]      4
5    adcd    6  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]      5
6    abcd    7  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]      2
7     cba    8  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]      3
```

Finally, I sum up the count by `group` as following (that is why at the beginning of the question, I said "group the data using the similarity vector for some metric calculation".

```
df_final = df.groupby("group").sum("cnt")
print(df_final)
```

The output is as follows:

```
group   cnt    
1        1
2       13
3       11
4        5
5        6
```

Hopefully the added example is clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the core problem is grouping strings with other strings based on their similarity. The similarity vectors seem like an (optional) means to an end; so, one can drop them entirely and go straight to grouping. The following solution takes `nC2` loop iterations i.e. `n! / 2*((n - 2)!)`. For example, 5 rows will take 10 loop iterations, 8 rows will take 28 loop iterations and so on. This will be the minimum number of comparisons that have to be made to cover all 2-element subsets of the set of rows.

Given the use of a dictionary, the solution below assumes no duplicate strings. I presume that you can pre-process your data to remove exact duplicates.

#### Solution

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

import pandas as pd

messages = ["ABC", "ABCD", "DCBA", "abcde", "CBDA", "abcd", "edcba"]
results = dict(zip(messages, [[] for _ in range(len(messages))]))

for idx, message in enumerate(messages):
    for comp_message in messages[idx + 1 :]:
        if similar(message, comp_message):
            results[message].append(comp_message)
            results[comp_message].append(message)

df = pd.DataFrame(results.items(), columns=["Message", "Similar-Message"])
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
  Message Similar-Message
0     ABC          [ABCD]
1    ABCD           [ABC]
2    DCBA          [CBDA]
3   abcde          [abcd]
4    CBDA          [DCBA]
5    abcd         [abcde]
6   edcba              []
```

#### Additional Info

Here is a small visualisation for 5 rows of strings showing what combinations of strings are compared based on their index. Comparisons are signified by the `*` and are carried out column-wise, then row-wise by the above solution (i.e. c1r2, c1r3, ... c1r5, c2r3, c2r4, c2r5, c3r4, c3r5, c4r5). When string 0 is compared with string 1 (i.e. `01`), and it's similar, string 1 is stored in string 0's similar string list, and string 0 is stored in string 1's similar string list, thus the symmetric `10` is handled: thereby minimising the number of iterations and similarity calculations that have to be performed.

```
00  10  20  30  40
01* 11  21  31  41
02* 12* 22  32  42
03* 13* 23* 33  43
04* 14* 23* 34* 44
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, which is a big step moving forward. My question is how can I make use of the column "Similar-Message" if I want to group the dataset finally? Let me add more information to my question to make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: I added one example to the question to show why I need the similarity vector since I need it to categorize messages into different groups and finally sum up the count for each group. Thank you for your input again.

Comment: @Sophia In your updated example, you've got the count as a sequence that simply increments by one, it doesn't actually seem to be counting anything, is this correct? Shouldn't the "count" by groups be based on matching similarity vectors i.e. in your example given, the count for groups 1-5 would be  1, 3, 2, 1, 1, respectively?

Comment: The `group` is used to sum up the `cnt` column in `df`. For example, the `cnt` for group `1` is `1`, while the `cnt` for group `2` is ```2 + 4 + 7 = 13```. Is that clear?

Comment: Added one more comment. The `cnt` in `df` indicates the number of occurrence for each message. Finally we want to sum up `cnt` based on the `group` column, and the `group` is based on the similarity vector.

Comment: @Sophia Is your desired final output groups with the corresponding sum total of the occurrences of each message in that group? The more things that are required the slower computation is going to be and the more storage required so I'm just trying to get clear on what is actually required by the end of processing.

Comment: The final expected output is the `df` output in my example without the `similarity` column.

Comment: I agree with you that the more we desire, the harder our life is. However, sometimes it is unavoidable. Thank you for your input again.

Comment: Can we speed up the process if we use PySpark? Just an open question.

Comment: @Sophia I'll have a look at this again tomorrow, didn't get any time today to go over it again.

Comment: I opened a new question for parallel computing  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76451988/parallelize-multiple-pairwise-comparisons-in-python) since I believe this question is beneficial for many folks.