# Parallelize multiple pairwise comparisons in Python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, pairwise

Consider we have a data frame with `10K` rows and `2` columns. The first column is the customer message, and the `cnt` is the frequency of that message. Below is a sample dataset:

```
    message cnt
0     ABC    1
1     abc    2
2     cba    1
3    abcd    3
4    dcsa    5
5    adcd    6
6    abcd    2
7     cba    3
```

I have to perform pairwise comparisons to compare text similarity between any two rows, and thus, there are `N^2` comparisons . I am looking for options to parallelize this process.

Below is the expected output. Since `row1` has `100%` similarity with itself, the similarity is `1`, but not similar enough with `row2`, and thus, it is `0`, etc.

```
   message  cnt         similarity
0     ABC    1  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1     abc    2  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
2     cba    1  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
3    abcd    3  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
4    dcsa    5  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
5    adcd    6  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
6    abcd    2  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
7     cba    3  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I have defined functions to justify the similarity between any two rows. Below is an reproducible example. Thank you for your input.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['ABC','abc','cba','abcd','dcsa','adcd','abcd','cba'], 
                  'cnt': [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]})

def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    coef = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2).ratio()
    if coef >= 0.80:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def similarity(x, df):
    sim_score = []
    for i in df['message']:
        sim_score.append(similarity_score(x, i))
    return sim_score

df['similarity'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: similarity(x, df)).astype(str)
```

Comment: What proportion of the "messages" in your actual data are duplicates?  If it is significant, you can make some hay by removing them from duplicate consideration.

Comment: Good question. There is no duplicate in my messages. I want to compare the similarity of any two messages, and if they are similar enough, then I will categorize them into one group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very lazy way to do it:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as tpe:
    df['similarity2'] = list(tpe.map(lambda x: [similarity_score(x, elem) for elem in df['message']], df['message']))
assert (df['similarity2'].astype(str) == df['similarity']).all()
```

If I wanted this to really rip, I'd probably use `numba`, which offers parallel execution of LLVM compiled code. You probably also only need to compute one side of the triangle, I think `SequenceMatcher` is commutative?

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe I did something wrong, but it seems that it does not speed up the computation time...

Comment: Try processpoolexecutor - also build a bunch of random data in the example so I can get a decent benchmark, then I can optimize a bit